# Trigger an action for every alphanumeric keypress

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have the following lines in a plugin's `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file:

```
...
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "table_editor_align", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.enable_table_editor", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\s*\\|", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "$", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
...
```

Instead of triggering this command only when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, I'd like to trigger this command **after every alphanumeric keypress** (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and why not also accents é, à, ç, etc. i.e. all characters that we use while writing)?

```
"keys": ["[a-zA-Z0-9_]"]
```

doesn't seem to work.

Note: the plugin is currently a subclass of [sublime_plugin.TextCommand](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand), and I think keeping this is mandatory for it to work. The plugin I'm trying to modify is https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor, I would like that auto-re-align is made automatically after each keypress, rather than after each CTRL+SHIFT+A like here:

[image]

Comment: You would be much better off writing a plugin subclassing [`sublime_plugin.EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) and making use of its `on_modified()` method.

Comment: @MattDMo the plugin is currently a subclass of sublime_plugin.TextCommand, and I think keeping this is mandatory for it to work. The plugin I'm trying to modify is https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to bind a key to a large class of keys at once, so in order to do what you want, you would have to create an individual mapping for each of the keys one at a time, which is rather unwieldy and quite likely not a good idea.

---

[edit]
There is actually a way to do this; I've added more information to the end of my answer
[/edit]

---

From some simple testing it would appear that the keys that you're interested in (that input text) are directly handled by the Sublime core unless you provide a mapping for them. That is to say, they subvert the normal command mechanism, meaning that you can't just catch whenever text is being inserted and reformat.

One way to go about this is, as suggested by MattDMO, to use an `on_modified` handler to track when the buffer is being modified and then trigger the realignment that way.

An example plugin that can do something like that is the following:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

class TableFormatEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self._views = dict()
        self.regex = re.compile(r"\s*\|")

    def on_modified(self, view):
        # Only for views with table editing enabled that are not already being
        # modified
        if (view.settings().get("enable_table_editor", False) and
                self._views.get(view.id(), False) is False):

            for s in view.sel():
                line = view.substr(view.line(s.begin()))
                prior = view.substr(s.begin() - 1) if s.begin() > 0 else ""

                # Only if all cursors are inside of a table row and the
                # character prior to the cursor is not a space
                if self.regex.match(line) is None or prior == " ":
                    return

            # Perform the realignment
            self._views[view.id()] = True
            view.run_command("table_editor_align")
            self._views[view.id()] = False

    def on_text_command(self, view, cmd, args):
        # Don't trigger reformatting while an undo is happening
        if cmd == "undo":
            self._views[view.id()] = True

    def on_post_text_command(self, view, cmd, args):
        # Undo is complete; resume reformat handling
        if cmd == "undo":
            self._views[view.id()] = False
```

This implements an event listener that triggers every time a view is modified. This means that text was added **or** deleted, and also covers things such as pastes (literally anything that modifies the buffer; more on that in a second).

The plugin does the same sort of context checking that the key binding does, to ensure that all of the available carets are currently inside of a table line, as if you invoke the command to realign the table otherwise, it throws an error.

Additionally, a check is also done to see if the last character added was a space. This is because the reformat seems to remove trailing spaces, which effectively blocks you from being able to enter a space anywhere in a table.

Assuming that all cursors are in table lines and did not just insert a space, the command to realign the table is executed on the current view.

The thing to watch for here is that realigning the table causes the contents of the buffer to be modified, which then triggers the plugin listener again, which realigns the table again, over and over in a loop until the plugin host crashes.

To stop that from happening, we keep a track of the views that should have their `on_modified` event ignored, adding the current view to the list prior to modifying the table and then removing it once we're done.

A side effect of what the plugin does is that any change you make inside of a table results in two modifications; the change that you made, and the change that realigns the table (even if it does not change). This means that in order to undo changes in the table, you sometimes have to press Undo more times than you might think.

This causes potential issues. For example, if you were to backspace at the start of a table row, that row and the previous row would be on the same line. The modification calls the realignment function, which formally makes the two rows one.

Now you're in a bit of a pickle because you can't undo the change; when you press undo once, it undoes the realignment, but in doing so it modifies the buffer, which triggers the realignment to immediately happen again.

In order to solve that problem, the event listener also listens for when an `undo` command is about to happen, and makes sure that while the undo is happening, the modification handler will not realign the table.

As I don't use this particular plugin, there may be similar edge cases for other scenarios that would need to be handled in this manner.

Performance may or may not suffer depending on how large a table you happen to be editing. In my (extremely simplistic) testing, the performance hit on small tables was negligible on my machine. Your mileage may vary, so it may potentially be a good idea to have extra checking in the code that stops it from triggering if the current file is over some line threshold or something along those lines.

---

[edit]

As it happens, there actually is a way to do something similar to what you originally asked. It is possible to assign a key binding that will trigger for any inserted character, although you still need a bit of glue plugin code to tie everything together (and a couple of usability issues remain pertaining to how the table plugin is doing the reformat).

The plugin code required is a command that will accept a character and insert the text as it normally would, but then also trigger the table alignment command.

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class TextAndAlignTableCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, character):
        self.view.run_command("insert", {"characters": character})
        if character != " ":
            self.view.run_command("table_editor_align")
```

This defines a command that takes a single argument of `character`, which it will insert into the buffer the way a character would normally be entered. Then, if the character is not a space, it also invokes the command to realign the table.

With this in place, the key binding to create is:

```json
{ "keys": ["<character>"], "command": "text_and_align_table", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.enable_table_editor", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\s*\\|", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "\\s*\\|.*$", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

This is basically the key binding that you mentioned above (which is the default for the underlying table plugin to trigger the reformat) with some slight modifications.

Firstly, the key is bound to the key `<character>`, which makes it potentially trigger for any character that would otherwise be inserted into the buffer.

Secondly, it uses our custom command from above which will first insert the text and then reformat the table.

Thirdly, the `following_text` context is modified so that it only triggers when it is at the end of a column in the table, so that it is possible to insert text into the middle of a column without having the cursor position jumped to the end of the column.

When bound this way, the binding will trigger for any single character, and will invoke the command provided with an argument that tells you what the character was. The binding itself can't have a modifier on it (e.g. `ctrl`, `shift`, etc), but the character you get is the one that would have otherwise been typed.

This is a lot cleaner and doesn't have the same problem as the code above w/regards to undo because all of the actions taken are part of the same edit operation.

Additionally, having the binding not trigger while inside of a column body removes the issue with being able to insert text in the middle of the column since the table realignment shifts the cursor location. This does leave the table unaligned, but the existing key binding can be used in this situation to rectify the issue.

On the other hand, it is still impossible to have spaces at the end of a column value (after a reformat) because the table reformat wants to remove them. To stop that from happening the underlying plugin would have to be modified to not do that, but that seems like it would compromise the table formatting somewhat.

Comment: Well, the code above will have the effect you want and realign the table on every edit. It's would be fairly easy to create a `TextCommand` that would insert a character and then realign the table, but then you would have to create a key binding to execute it for every character you might want to enter into a table.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OdatNurd, it works :) 
Only problem: undo doesn't work... (you mentioned such edge cases in your development), have you tried it with the plug in ? Maybe it's just a small something. Any idea?

Comment: Any operation that modifies the buffer while the plugin is active is taking at least two actions (one to insert the text and one to reformat the table), so you may need to press undo a couple of times to get back to where you expect it to. Possibly more if the reformat operation makes more than one edit, but I don't know if that's what it does or not (it didn't in my tests at any rate)

Comment: I tried : go in the table, press "hello", CTRL Z, CTRL Z (10 times or more...) : nothing happens : "hello" stays in the table

Comment: Hmm. it doesn't do that for me. Not sure what could be going on there.

Comment: Thanks once again @OdatNurd. But unfortunately, there are too many edge cases. [See here](http://i.imgur.com/I3Wvkne.gif) for example what happens when you want to add something in the middle of a cell : the caret moves at the end all the time. Also when you add spaces at the end, the alignment doesn't work... It's a shame because it would be great to have a niceTableEditor plugin! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that myself. I think the only way to fix that would be inside of the table reformatting code from the plugin itself; it doesn't try to maintain where the cursor was when you ran the realignment. That job is a little more involved, though. :)

Comment: @Basj I modified the answer above; it might be a little closer to what you originally wanted, although the issue with spaces at the end of a column after alignment remains.

Comment: Would you have an idea @OdatNurd to solve the little problem with spaces? Also if you can put all your enhancements in a fork of https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor, would be great for future users. I'd be happy to do another bounty!

Comment: I don't know if there's a good way to do that; it's a side effect of having the table want to keep the columns as narrow as possible when it reflows them. At a guess the entire logic for reformatting the table would need to be rewritten in order to get it to conditionally do that so that it could be applied only when a full manual reflow is requested. Unfortunately I don't have much free time to work on something like that ;/

Comment: Oh I understand of course. Maybe just a consolidation of all your current enhancements as a fork on github? That would be useful :)

Comment: Hi @OdatNurd, as you're a SublimeText expert, you might have an idea for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276904/move-line-to-next-section-with-sublimetext. I'll probably start a bounty too! Thank you in advance if you have an idea